# 405 Method Not Allowed getting couchdb document from javascript

Tags: javascript, get, couchdb, vuejs2

I'm working with quasar-framework proyect and a couchdb database called **product**.

What I try is to make a **GET** request to a certain document but I'm having the following error:

**Error**

```
:8080/#/:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5984/product. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

vue-resource.es2015.js?fc90:1085 OPTIONS http://localhost:5984/product 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

**Index.vue**

```
    getProyect() {
        var deferred = Q.defer()
        var url = "http://localhost:5984/product/product1"
        Vue.http.get(url)
        .then(
            function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data)
                console.log("success getting response")
            },
            function (error) {
                var msg = 'N/A'
                console.log('ERROR get:', error)
                deferred.reject(msg)
            }
        )
        return deferred.promise
    }
```

*-Doing the same request through **postman** works correctly.*

You can see the cors configuration using curl:

```
curl -X GET admin:admin@localhost:5984/_config/cors
//Output
{"credentials":"true","origins":"*","headers":"accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer, x-csrf-token","methods":"GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE, OPTIONS"}
```

I also had the problem of allowing cors on the `couchdb` server and solved it by editing the **local.ini** but this one has no idea how to fix it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using nginx as a reverse proxy to couchdb. Now my app is running on port 80.

In `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` I have added:

```
location /couchdb {
    rewrite /couchdb/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5984;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

And now my **Index.vue** looks like:

```
getProyect() {
    var deferred = Q.defer()
    var url = "http://localhost/couchdb/product/product1" //where db = product documentID = product1
    Vue.http.get(url)
    .then(
        function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data)
            console.log("success getting response")
        },
        function (error) {
            var msg = 'N/A'
            console.log('ERROR get:', error)
            deferred.reject(msg)
        }
    )
    return deferred.promise
}
```

**SOURCE**: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/COUCHDB/Nginx+as+a+proxy

**EDIT**: Another solution It's just to use [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) client.

Comment: could you please expand on the alternative solution